# Cannot access password: it is private in User

Tags: kotlin, spring-security

I want to store and access password from database but when I go to access password from database by the help entity class and spring security `UserDetails` it throws an error make password private, when I go to store password it throws make password public. I don't know how to handle this type of issue in spring Security. I implement the `UserDetails` for `User` and it override some function like `getPassword()` and its return type is `String` so I return password as string argument. But here is the issue when I declare password field in UserEntity Class as public `getPassword()` throw an error

```
Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getPassword()Ljava/lang/String;):
```

When make the Password field private I get another error while Store the data in database

```
\main\kotlin\com\nilmani\mychat\service\UserService.kt: (38, 14): Cannot access 'password': it is private in 'User'
```

User.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.model

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
import java.time.LocalDate

@Document
open class User(
    @Id
    var id: String? ="",
    var userName: String? ="",
    var password: String? ="",
    var email: String? ="",
    var createdAt: LocalDate? =LocalDate.now(),
    var updatedAt: LocalDate? = LocalDate.now(),
    var active:Boolean=false,
    @NotNull
    var userProfile: Profile?,
    @NotNull
    var role: MutableSet<Role>? = HashSet()
    ) {
    constructor(user: User?):this(
        user?.id, user?.userName, user?.password, user?.email, user?.createdAt,
        user?.updatedAt, user?.active == true, user?.userProfile, user?.role
    )

    constructor() : this(null)
}
```

InstaUserDetails.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.model

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import java.util.stream.Collectors

class InstaUserDetails :User(),UserDetails {
    override fun getAuthorities(): MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority> {
        return role
            ?.stream()
            ?.map { role -> SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+role.name) }
            ?.collect(Collectors.toList())!!
    }
    override fun getPassword() : String {
        return "password"
    }
    override fun getUsername(): String {
        return "username"
    }
    override fun isAccountNonExpired(): Boolean {
        return isAccountNonExpired
    }
    override fun isAccountNonLocked(): Boolean {
        return isAccountNonLocked
    }
    override fun isCredentialsNonExpired(): Boolean {
       return isCredentialsNonExpired
    }
    override fun isEnabled(): Boolean {
        return isEnabled
    }
}
```

UserService.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.service

import com.nilmani.mychat.model.Role
import com.nilmani.mychat.model.User
import com.nilmani.mychat.repository.UserRepository
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.util.*


@Service
class UserService {
    val log : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService::class.java)
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider

    fun register(user:User, role:Role): User {
        log.info("Register user {}", user.userName)
        if (userRepository.existsByUserName(user.userName!!) == true) {
            log.warn("UserName already Exist", user.userName)
        }
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(user.email!!) == true) {
            log.warn("This email already Registred", user.email)
        }
        user.active = true
        user.password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.password)
        user.role = user.role
        /**it auto automatically get the user type from role due to some conflict  set role provided by user*/
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }
}
```

If make Password public I get an error in `InstaUserDetails` class at
`getPassword()`. If make password field private in the `User` class I get error in `UserService` class at password saving. How to handle this multiple issue in a single entity class. I applied booth mutable and private key on password  like private var password:String?=""  but I get error at password save in `register()` which define in my `UserService` class.

Comment: May also be worth pointing out that, for security reasons, storing a password directly is usually a very bad idea; it's usually safer to store a _hash_ of the password. (That way, you can verify the user has entered the correct password — but a malicious actor who gets access to your DB doesn't get all your users' passwords.) Encoding the password is better than nothing, but can still be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the password parameter private and explicitly create a getter and setter for it.

```kotlin
open class User(
    private var password: String? = "",
    private var username: String? = "",
    // ...
) {
    constructor() : this(null)

    open fun getPassword(): String? {
        return password
    }

    open fun setPassword(password: String?) {
        this.password = password
    }
}
```

Note that in `InstaUserDetails`, you don't need to override `getPassword()` if you simply want to inherit `getPassword()` from `User`.